# Elementor API - Conditional display with SELECT2 Control

Tags: php, elementor

I'm trying to conditionally display some Elementor Controls for a custom widget I'm working on based on a SELECT2 Control, but can't discover how and Elementor documentation says nothing about it.

Since I'll offer several options, switch is not good; and simple Select can't handle multiple choices, so I need Select2. Here's my SELECT2 Control and a HEADING Example Control

```
<?php
$this->add_control(
    'model',
    [
        'label'        => __('Model', 'text-domain'),
        'type'         => Controls_Manager::SELECT2,
        'options'      => [
            'grid' => esc_html__('Grid', 'text-domain'),
            'list' => esc_html__('List', 'text-domain'),
            'thumb' => esc_html__('Thumb', 'text-domain'),
            // .. more options
        ],
        'default'      => ['grid', 'thumb'],
        'label_block' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
        'render_type'  => 'template',
        'frontend_available' => true,
    ]
);

$this->add_control(
    'grid_hr',
    [
        'label'         => esc_html__( 'Grid options', 'text-domain' ),
        'type'          => Controls_Manager::HEADING,
        'separator'     => 'before',
        'conditions'    => [ // not working
            'terms' => [
                [
                    'name'      => 'model',
                    'operator'  => 'in',
                    'value'     => ['grid'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]
);
```

I've tried several ways of checking but had no success yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to make it work. The correct way was using 'contains' operator. SInce I had several controls, turned these conditions into a function to make my life easier. Gonna share my solution here.

Helper function to summarize my conditions:

```
function nav_conditions($value, $extras = false, $relation = 'and'){

    $conditions['terms'][] = [
        'name' => 'navigation', // control name
        'operator' => 'contains',
        'value' => $value, // value
    ];
    $conditions['relation'] = $relation;

    // Check for extra conditions
    if($extras != false){
        $conditions['terms'][] = $extras;
    }

    return $conditions;
}
```

With this function I can condition my controls to check for a SELECT2 value like following:

```
$this->add_control(
    'hr_arrows',
    [
        'label' => esc_html__( 'Arrows', 'text-domain' ),
        'type' => Controls_Manager::HEADING,
        'separator' => 'before',
        'conditions' =>  $this->nav_conditions('arrows'), // without extra conditions
    ]
);
```

If I need to insert more conditions:

```
'conditions' =>  $this->nav_conditions(
    'dots',
    [
        'name' => 'advanced_dots_size',
        'operator' => '==',
        'value' => 'yes',
    ]
),
```